# NLTK detect linguistic short forms/abbreviations

Tags: python, nltk

Is there a way to use for example something like a dictionary and detect linguistic short forms / abbreviations of tokens:

> - "c'mon" -> Come on
> - "'ll" -> will

***Sry for no code but i don't find any possibility to solve my problem yet***

Comment: I'd say that you can't do this without a lexicon, but that seems too naive. Yet anything else (like attempting to sequence-match an abbreviation to a known lexicon of words) would be much more complex